# How to keep the w/h:auto resizable ability of an img inside figure/img/figcaption

Tags: css, image-resizing, figure

Keeping the w/h:auto resizable ability of an img when its parent is set to display:table and the parent's w/h is not 100%? It seems obvious that if the parent's w/h is not set then its child's w/h:auto makes not much sense. My point is, I want to keep the "resizable ability" of an img if it is inside figure/img/figcaption. Description of the problem:

Big images in a gallery we may want to resize to fit the window size if bigger. If it is just an image it can be done easily setting the image's w/h to auto (and maxw/maxh to 100%), with adding margin:auto we get it even nicely centered. But how to achieve the same with figure/img/figcaption altogether? As we want the figcaption's width to match the width of the image dynamically on the fly (not in px) we need to set figcaption display:table-caption (plus caption-side:bottom) and figure display:table. But once we set the figure display:table and its w/h is not set (or is set to auto, otherwise figcaption width will not match the img's), image w/h:auto don't work any more (not much surprisingly) and we get a not desirable 100% of w/h of the img (will not fit into the window if bigger). Is there any CSS only solution how to keep w/h:auto of the img or somehow achieve the same resizable ability if it is inside figure/img/figcaption?

There are many great approaches out there of how to center or resize elements or images, for example here <*codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt*> or here <*codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/jhsJL*>, but these and many more elsewhere don't work with a set of figure/img/figcaption (or I was unable to make it work). I am troubling myslef with it literally for days long with no clear answer.

In other words, what I need: A figure/img/figcaption set is centered altogether, they will resize if the image is bigger than window size, figcaption must match the width of the image width. All should be done with CSS and without setting anything in px.

Answer (score 1):

So `<img>` and `<figcaption>` all go inside a `<figure>` element. All three are block elements.

You would just set the height and width of your `<figure>` element, then add a margin auto like you said.

Then set in your css:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

And now your image and your caption will always be the width of the `figure` element, the text will always be centered under the image, and the larger element will always be centered on the page.

EDIT: Adding 100% as a width or height to something means "100% of the parent element". So if you set a width/height for your `figure` element, the elements inside can be 100% and they won't break the element. Again, all three are block elements already, so you don't need to re-declare them as `display: table-caption` or whatever. Just use the strength of the block element as it is.

EDIT 2: OKAY. Here's what you need:

Set the figure to a specific height and width in CSS.

Then set the img and figure inside your fig caption to: width: 100%; height: auto;.

Your html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <figure>
        <img src="">
        <figcaption>Some Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
```

Now you need a media query in your CSS to handle the size of `<figure>`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    figure {
        width: /*Whatever width you want*/
        height: /*Whatever height oyu want*/
    }
}
```

Then repeat your media query for different break points.

If you still think I'm wrong, make a codepen or fiddle with an example and I'll help you from there.

## EDIT 3

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating that you can make a responsive image and element using relative measurements in % and maintaining the image centered to the things around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/o2rv4t9h/1/

Comment: As I wrote you cannot set the w/h of figure (with display:table) as you suggest because this way the resize ability of the image is lost. That's the point!
If figure {display: table; width: auto; height: auto;} the figcaption works fine but the img is NOT resized to fit the window. If figure {width: 100%; height: 100%;} and display is NOT table the img is resized but the figcaption doesn't match the img width.

Comment: Check it now and see if it helps. You need to learn about media queries if you want to change object sizes with the screen.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, sorry, but you are repeating yourself saying "Set the figure to a specific height and width". But once we set it the resize ability of the image is lost. Also if you set 100% width to an image it looses its original size. I want to resize an image only if it is bigger than the window/viewport.

Comment: OK, as I understand your edit2 you are trying the lost resize ability of the img compensate by using @media query with (how many?) break points. It is really not the way I would go. A resizable image should be a responsive one dynamically changing its dimensions as you can see here <codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/jhsJL>. I will create a fiddle tomorrow for better clarity. Anyway thanks!

Comment: I've edited a third time with a demo fiddle that has an image dynamically change its dimensions, and stay in proportion. Copy and paste it to an .html file and resize your screen if you don't feel like changing the css in the fiddle.

Comment: The image is not resizing/fitting to window if the browser window is smaller. Either decrease the browser window or try a big image to see what I mean. You get scrollbars.

Comment: In my gallery I have overall 900-950px height images. If you got a HD monitor they should show as they are. But if you have a smaller monitor or you just resizing your browser the images should resize with it and fit the window without scrollbars.

Comment: To do this man you are literally going to need a media query for the parent element. There is no other way to do it unless you want javascript. unless, like my fiddle, you use relative spacial units to define the size of the parent - like %s or ems.